# Loading JSON data in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jsonreader

I'm having troubles when showing my json data in jqGrid.

I've searched a lot in this forum and tried various forms to make it work. I apologize if this was already answered but I really need help with this one.

At the server page I was only using **JavaScriptSerializer** to send the data and the **jsonreader** function with the default parameters (this worked ok).

I now need to paginate and have changed my server page code to work with the **sidx**, **sord**, **page**, **rows** parameters.

The resulting string from the server looks like this:

```
{"total":"344","page":"1","records":"8577","root":[{"Id":"1","SerialNumber":"132","Name":"ServerName"},...]}
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        url:'https://server/handlerpage.ashx',
        colNames:['Id','SerialNumber','Name'],
        colModel :[         
                {name:'Id', index:'Id', jsonmap:"Id", width:20},
                {name:'Name', index:'Name', jsonmap:"Name", width:120},
                {name:'SerialNumber', index:'SerialNumber', jsonmap:"SerialNumber", width:100}],    
        jsonreader: {repeatitems:false,id:'Id',root:'root'},
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum:25,
        rowList:[25,50,75,100],
        sortname: 'Id',
        viewrecords:true,
        gridview: true,
        height:"400",
        width:"700",
        caption: 'Select from existing server',
        loadtext:'Loading, please wait'
      }).navGrid("#pager", { edit: false, add: false, search: true, del: false });
```

Comment: The main error in your code is the usage of `jsonreader` instead of `jsonReader`. You can remove all `jsonmap` properties and `index` too. I'll recommend you additionally never use `url` like `'https://server/handlerpage.ashx'`. Corresponds to Ajax [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you have to use the same `https://server/` prefix as the current page. So you should better use `url: 'handlerpage.ashx'` or `url: '/handlerpage.ashx'`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, I tested jsonReader (with capital R) and it did worked. Also changed the url to comply with the policy and worked too.

Comment: You are welcome! Sometimes the error is very small (only one letter), but because of this it could be difficult to find it.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use json data as a response from a query the response has to be formatted correctly.  It is difficult to determine what is the correct response and how to get it from the documents. More problems can occur as a result of your server settings generating a warning as part of the response which will cause the grid not to load.

From the documents this is the default json reader, meaning if you format your response correctly you don't need to add anything / a custom json reader.

```
jsonReader : { 
  root: "rows", 
  page: "page", 
  total: "total", 
  records: "records", 
  repeatitems: true, 
  cell: "cell", 
  id: "id",
  userdata: "userdata",
  subgrid: { 
     root:"rows", 
     repeatitems: true, 
     cell:"cell" 
  }
```

First make sure you have the right response format.  `{"page":1,"total":1,"records":"2","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","mydata1"]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","mydata2"]}]}`

No sample is given on the docs page but the above is correct if you only have two columns in your grid. You need to get your server query / parsing of your server query and values passed to the page that runs your sever side scripts to return this format. The example.php page from the documents gives you all the values you need.

This code will give you the proper header, to avoid error warnings and matches up with the response from above.  Also note that in the docs they do not add the apostrophes around the indexes for the associative array index names.  That will fail.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');$responce = new stdClass();$responce->page = $page;$responce->total = $total_pages;$responce->records = $count;$i=0;while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {$responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['ID'];$responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['ID'],$row['entity_name']); $i++; } echo json_encode($responce);
```

To rehash what is missing in the docs (it is possible that I just missed them and even if, the documents for jQgrid are epic/a masters work):
1.  No mention of the need for a header statement for json (it is clear with the XML examples)
2.  No sample of what a working returned string should look like
3.  Lack of proper formatting of the associative array indexes.
4.  No mention of how to avoid a PHP warning being returned as part of the response

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
jsonReader: {
    root: 'rows',
    page: 'page',
    total: 'total',
    records: 'records',
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: 'cell',
    id: 'id',
    userdata: 'userdata'
}
```

Comment: That did not work either. I'm wondering if the 'root':[{...}] is wrong, when I in the jsonReader I change the root tag 'rows' or other value the grid shows the loading string and stays there.

Comment: I changed it a bit and it worked: jsonReader: {root: 'rows',page: 'page',total: 'total',records: 'records',repeatitems: false,id: 'id'} Thank you Two Seeds

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the server side script is returning proper json string with [HEADERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file)

Further check the [demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) site and JSON example

Comment: I've tried both application/json and text/json but did not solved my problem. I also tried text/plain (which work the first time before pagination) but that did not work either. Funny thing that the pagination bar is working fine, I can see the number of pages and change them, it's like the grid would not want to read the root part of the server response.

Comment: I used: text/plain, text/json, application/json and they all worked after changing the jsronReader. Thank you.